# postcss-cli: override the output file extensions

Tags: javascript, css, postcss, postcss-cli

I want it to process `.dev.css` files and output the result in the same folder but only with the `.css` extension.

**Expected result:**

```sh
src
  login.dev.css <-- input file
  login.css <-- output file
```

I'm using `postcss-cli` like this:

```sh
postcss src/**/*.dev.css --base src --dir src --ext css --watch --config postcss.config.js
```

**Current result:**

It does not remove the `.dev` extension, so it overrides the same file and result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have the output created in the input directory. That aside, `postcss-cli` doesn't have a generic way to do what you want. It does have a file-specific way to do it, though: `postcss-cli login.dev.css -o login.css`